# how to immediately run a function while an element.innerHTML change?

Tags: javascript

First,I planed to set an element's **innerHTML** a  `getter` and `setter`
But I found it wouldn't work,I know why it wouldn't,but is there a way to accomplish this task?
Thanks

Comment: The idea is to control all the `.innerHTML` changes and then manually call your function whenever a change occurs.

Comment: You probably get some better help if you explain the overall problem you are trying to solve. You already presented a possible solution (call x when y changes), you should describe the problem instead.

Comment: Do you only care about changes that the JS application makes, or Client initiated changes as well? (e.g. `<textarea>`s)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look into [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents). There is poor browser support for these events, but they may help you to catch the moment when innerHTMl, i.e. DOM is changed. Take a look into `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you can set timeout and check dom changes manually after some period of time. Once you detect the change you can fire application level event or execute a function.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. ["*DOM Mutation events as currently specified and implemented
are widely viewed as fatally flawed*"](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JulSep/0779.html). From what I've picking up, mutation events should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try DOMNodeInserted event.
jQuery:

```
$('.yourElement').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    alert('New content: ' + $(e.target).innerHTML);
});
```

It is not cross browser compatible. But this might not be an issue depending on your project.

You might want to periodically check for changes with setInterval().